# Hat/circumflex above letter in LibreOffice Writer

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

I would like to have arbitrary letters in normal text (not formula mode) with a hat/circumflex above it. For instance, it should look like this: Ĝ.

How can I achieve this in LibreOffice Writer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example character is [LATIN CAPITAL LETTER G WITH CIRCUMFLEX](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/11c/index.htm), which decomposes into G and [U+0302](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0302/index.htm).

So enter `G`, then go to `Insert -> Special Character` and search for U+302.  Double-click to insert.

For convenience, set up Keyman or MSKLC or even AutoHotkey to do this with a key combination such as <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd>.